# how to get only distinct value with join statement and 2 databases

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have 2 databases and want to get 1 table out of it
from database1.table1 I want to take one column called deeplink
from database2.table2 I want to take 4 column name , brand_name , category_name and item_sold_30d

this is my current query however am getting duplicated in columns name

how to get rid of it?

```
select distinct(b.name),b.item_sold_30d , b.brand_name ,b.category_name, a.deeplink
from database1.table1 a
INNER join database2.table2 b on b.name = a.product_name
where brand_name ='' order by b.item_sold_30d DESC
```

the code is fine but I'm getting duplicate name which I don't want.

my output
[here is the output of my query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJbKg.png)

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Please correct your tags.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` - and works in the whole selected rows. Skip those extra parentheses and simply write `select distinct b.name, b.item_sold_30d ...` to make code clearer.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images.) Simplify if possible. [mcve].

Comment: still getting a duplication , I forgot to add that my table contains Vietnamese name is it because of that ?

Comment: @samirahassan . . . When there are multiple matches, what row do you want?  Your question is not complete.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I want to have the columns mentioned but with no duplication since I'm combining to tables

Comment: please provide the output of your query and what you are trying to achieve as the result.

Comment: @Annamalai I added the output please help me to find the error

Comment: @samirahassan the image you posted is not showing the entire values in deeplink column. could you please check if the value of deeplink in each row is same or different?

Comment: @Annamalai its different links I checked before

Comment: if it is different you cannot remove the duplicate names with the deeplinks column in the select and you cannot say has duplicates. if you remove the deeplink column then you will not get duplicate name.

Comment: @Annamalai so is there any other solution I need to have only the distinct names

Comment: Could you please provide what results are you expecting? if you say that you need only one row with a name, then which deeplink value should be in that row?

Comment: @Annamalai I am expecting the name(distinct ) , brand_name , deeplink , category_name from both databases

Comment: @Annamalai this line on b.name = a.product_name will get me only the values in both tables so if lets say I have the name 3 times with different deeplink I am only interested in taking 1 name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want distinct names, just select the `distinct(b.name)` as below

```
select distinct(b.name)
from database1.table1 a
INNER join database2.table2 b on b.name = a.product_name
where brand_name ='' order by b.item_sold_30d DESC
```

If you have multiple `columns` in the `select`, even if you use `distinct(b.name)` it will fetch you distinct rows with all the `columns` mentioned in the `select`.

**Note:** `distinct` cannot be applied for a part of `columns` in a `select` statement. it will apply for all `columns` specified in the `select`. because of which you get duplicate names in your result, but those result will be distinct as an entire row.

```
select distinct(b.name),b.item_sold_30d , b.brand_name ,b.category_name, a.deeplink
from database1.table1 a
INNER join database2.table2 b on b.name = a.product_name
where brand_name ='' order by b.item_sold_30d DESC
```

**Update from the comments section of the Question:**

please run this sample fiddle and check out the two results. unless you decide what to be done with column `deeplink` you cannot remove the duplicate rows.
[dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7pxr4rsgtop6eZwqJXpsGS/0)

If you don't care about the deeplink and fine with any one value then use the query below.

**Update:**

```
SELECT name
    ,item_sold_30d
    ,brand_name
    ,category_name
    ,deeplink
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT b.name,b.item_sold_30d , b.brand_name ,b.category_name, a.deeplink, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.name,b.item_sold_30d , b.brand_name ,b.category_name ORDER BY a.deeplink) as rowId
FROM TABLE1 a
INNER JOIN TABLE2 b ON b.name = a.product_name
WHERE brand_name ='' ORDER BY b.item_sold_30d DESC
) dt
WHERE dt.rowId = 1
```

[dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cGW3ehMTQVwvDdzk4EYmRS/2)

Comment: thanks for replying to me @Annamalai then how to add the other columns in the statement ?

Comment: you can add other columns with distinct, but it will not just work for name, it will select the distinct rows with all columns mentioned.

Comment: if you still need clarification or help in achieving the result, please provide the output of your current query and what you are trying to achieve as the result

Comment: thank you for the solution however I got only one row

Comment: did you use the above query to get the result?

Comment: I updated the query with ```Partition by name```, you should get one row for each name now.

Comment: when I usually add limit statement at the end because I query on large database but now if I remove the query it works ,however from item_sold_30d I got I can see that is not the highest

Comment: check this out   https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cGW3ehMTQVwvDdzk4EYmRS/3

Comment: @annmalai thank you so much although my explanation was a little bit confusing yet you understood everything you are genius!